# Swipe across multiple tableviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to be able to swipe between different tableviews within the same viewcontroller. Here is an example from Instagram:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a recommended way to accomplish this while limiting complexity / using Storyboard as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use view controller containment — add multiple UITableViewControllers as child view controllers and switch between them using UIView frame animations.

Comment: Okay. So I'm thinking of placing a containerView in my viewController. And placing a pageviewController inside that containerView.This pageViewController will then manage the two separate tableViewControllers that I want to swipe between.. Will update with example code after I implement.

Comment: @vikzilla Did you manage to accomplish the task? I want to do the same..